# Managing sound channels

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm currently working on my menu structure and the options menu. I'm using the Director API to transition between scenes and use a custom save/load system.

I'm trying to make it so the user can switch music on and off. I've got it working, however not in the most optimized way (since it stops ALL sounds).

Main.lua

```
bgMusic = audio.loadSound( "sounds/Torukia.mp3" )
musicIsPlaying = false
```

mainMenu.lua

```
if musicIsPlaying == false then
        if gameSettings.soundOn == true then
            backgroundMusicChannel = audio.play( bgMusic, { loops=-1 } )
            musicIsPlaying = true
        elseif gameSettings.soundOff == true then
            musicIsPlaying = false
        end
    end
end
```

optionsMenu.lua

```
local function toggleSound( event )
    if event.phase == "ended" then
        if gameSettings.soundOn == true then
            gameSettings.soundOn = false
            gameSettings.soundOff = true
            audio.stop( )
    soundBtn:setFillColor( 255,0,0 )
        elseif gameSettings.soundOff == true then
            gameSettings.soundOn = true
            gameSettings.soundOff = false
            backgroundMusicChannel = audio.play( bgMusic, { loops=-1 } )
    soundBtn:setFillColor( 0,255,0 )
        end
        saveSettings(gameSettings, "gameSettings.json")
    end
end
```

Can I create global sound channels? That would be helpful. I've tried looking through the documentation, and searching for answers, but I couldnt find much regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version, you can specify which channel you want to play or stop

Main.lua

```
bgMusicChannel = 1 -- can be 1-32
bgMusic = audio.loadSound( "sounds/Torukia.mp3" )
musicIsPlaying = false
```

mainMenu.lua

```
if musicIsPlaying == false then
        if gameSettings.soundOn == true then
            backgroundMusicChannel = audio.play( bgMusic, { loops=-1,channel = bgMusicChannel } )
            musicIsPlaying = true
        elseif gameSettings.soundOff == true then
            musicIsPlaying = false
        end
    end
end
```

optionsMenu.lua

```
local function toggleSound( event )
    if event.phase == "ended" then
        if gameSettings.soundOn == true then
            gameSettings.soundOn = false
            gameSettings.soundOff = true
            audio.stop( bgMusicChannel )
    soundBtn:setFillColor( 255,0,0 )
        elseif gameSettings.soundOff == true then
            gameSettings.soundOn = true
            gameSettings.soundOff = false
            backgroundMusicChannel = audio.play( bgMusic, { loops=-1, channel = bgMusicChannel } )
    soundBtn:setFillColor( 0,255,0 )
        end
        saveSettings(gameSettings, "gameSettings.json")
    end
end
```

Comment: That worked wonderfully, and required hardly any change of my code. And it helped me understand sound channels a bit better. Win-win-win!